# Wicket Framework DropDownChoice

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to get selected value of dropdownchoice in wicket framework , but i am unable to get it.
How can i get selected value of DropDownChoice on the change event of dropdownchoice ???
Thanks.
I

Comment: Show some code, paste the error ... "It doesn't work" doesn't help us understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy, all you have to do is use an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`:

```
DropDownChoice<String> ddc = new DropDownChoice<String>("ddc", model, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
ddc.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("selected: " + model.getObject());
    }
});
```

Comment: Take into account that this ajax behavior will update the DropDownChoice's ModelObject, and perform its validations. If validations fail, `onError` will be called instead of `onUpdate`. Notice this has a drawback; `FormValidators` involving this component will not automatically execute. If you only want to get the input, without updating the model object, override [`getUpdateModel()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.html#getUpdateModel()) and return false.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more idiomatic to use OnChangeAjaxBehavior instead?

Answer (score 2):

`PropertyModel` is good choice for such problems. `MyObject` is an object and has a string `name`.I have override the `toString()` method in it to name and it is working properly.I suggest using this method.

```
topicDropDown = new DropDownChoice<MyObject>("wicktID", new PropertyModel<MyObject>       (this.object, "exp"), new LoadableDetachableModel<List<MyObject>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<MyObject> load() {
            return top.getAllObjects();

        }
```

Comment: It may late.Thanks god that Nishant found his answer.